# getUserMedia audio not working as expected

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to use getUserMedia to connect user's mic to internal nodes.
I've tried the Google example at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/audio/ and it works just fine in Chrome.
I've then downloaded the source and tried that on my own website. Now it doesn't work! The page renders but the audio doesn't play. The URL is http://www.rwilson.org.uk/webrtc/src/content/getusermedia/audio/

The console message is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined
    at main.js:36"
That line is:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
```

How can I find out what's going on?
Does that point to a problem with my website (security perhaps)?

**New info**: I have now run the Google example code from my localhost (running on my Chromebook with Web Server for Chrome), and it works.
So the problem must be with my own (hosted) server. Not sure how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

If the current document isn't loaded securely, navigator.mediaDevices will be **undefined**, and you cannot use getUserMedia().

Source [MediaDevices.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: Understood. Your source says "getUserMedia() is a powerful feature which can only be used in secure contexts; in insecure contexts, navigator.mediaDevices is undefined, preventing access to getUserMedia(). A secure context is, in short, a page loaded using HTTPS or the file:/// URL scheme, or a page loaded from localhost." My web site is, I think, secure - it is loaded via https. So where do I look next?

Comment: check if `window.isSecureContext` agrees with your opinion about being secure

Comment: @keble The link you shared is not secured. I checked that and it was not HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks - I will check with my website hosts